# Ruby arguments passing issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In the below code when I run it takes three arguments but third argument should be taken only strings and it should take either EIT, TC,pay. If that particular words are not given properly then it should prompt in outpput use EIT,PC, Pay.

```
fail "3 arguments required, #{ARGV.length} provided" unless ARGV.length == 3
fail "Not correct current ruild, #{ARGV[0]} provided" unless ARGV[0] =~ /^[0-9]{2}.0.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}/
fail "Not correct next build, #{ARGV[1]} provided" unless ARGV[1] =~ /^[0-9]{2}.0.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}/
```

ARGV[3]= { EIT, TC,pay} -- when I run it it is showing an error syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting

Comment: yeah, so? What's the question?

Comment: ARGV[3]= { EIT, TC,pay}  --when I run it it is showing an error syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>  .can you please help me.

Comment: `fail 'blah' unless %w(EIT PC Pay).includes? ARGV[2]`

Comment: fail "The third Argument required should be from below strings,#{ARGV[2]} provided" unless %w(EIT PC Pay).includes?ARGV[2]                          output shows an error:                                            undefined method `includes?' for #<Array:0x007fa4f2880f60> (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 1):

```
fail 'blah' unless %w(EIT PC Pay).include? ARGV[2]
```

Note that the method is `.include?` and not `.includes`. It's worth looking at the ruby docs at all the methods on Array and Enumerable and getting familiar with them. Have fun!